# How to generally enlarge a website's width with the help of CSS?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Let's say that I am an admin of [a certain website](http://www.wooders.sk/).

I am using latest release of Wordpress, my theme is a child theme of a theme called "Twenty Fourteen". I am using Mozilla Firebug to inspect elements I want to edit.

The page does not display in full width and there is still some unused space left (it is visible on the right). I would like to widen the page. How to do this? I have a Full Width template, setting all pages to this however does not work.

I am looking for a CSS solution (to edit the style.css of my child theme).

If anyone could help me, I would be really thankful. :)

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: It's not a "full-width" site...it has `max-width: 1260px;` Start there.

Comment: Please, could you be more specific? Where have you found this part of the code? I have been looking for it for hours already.

Also, to solve this, what should I add to the style.css file to guarantee a full width display?

Comment: Just inspect your site with the Developer Tools that come with your browser and you can see where these widths are defined.

Comment: Thank you. I have found the root of these settings.


    .site {
     background-color: #fff;
     max-width: 1260px;
     position: relative;
    }


How to set the width to a full width setting? I do not want to be too specific in setting the values to a larger number, I want it to be dynamically flexible (to always appear as a full width on whatever the device)

Comment: If you delete it it will default to 100% wide.

Answer (score 1):

So you want a full width page?

I've got some suggestion for you:

**1. Use a CSS Framework like Bootstrap**

Bootstrap will allow you to make a full width page without any problems. On top of that it will make your website responsive. [Read more...](http://getbootstrap.com/).

**2. Use your own CSS**

You need to make your body use all the space there is. You **can't** just use

```
body
width: 100%;
height: 100;
}
```

This would make the body take as much space as the children needs.
The body has always some margin and padding. So you need to get rid of that too.

```
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

The last step in your CSS would be a fixed position for all 4 sides and make the position relative:

```
body{
position: relative;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
}
```

So your final CSS should look like this:

```
body{
  position: relative;
  top: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

I suggest you to use a Framework, which makes your workflow alot easier.

Regards,
Megajin

Comment: So you are basically advising me to abandon Wordpress-oriented development and switch to Bootstrap? Or is it possible to somehow use the Bootstrap within Wordpress made themes?

Comment: Wordpress is your Content Management System. Which holds your content. The Content is show through your Theme (the view). You can use Bootstrap within a Wordpress theme. Actually all new themes are using a somehow responsive CSS Framework (selfmade or e.g. Bootstrap). If you don't want to use Bootstrap or any other Framwork, you can use my provided CSS Code in your page too.

Comment: Thank you very much for mentioning Bootstrap. I am currently watching a tutorial on how to master Bootstrap (it looks like it a very handy tool). In the meantime, I have used the code you provided in the style.css of the child theme I am using. It should override the parent settings and just work. However, it does not. I think it has something to do with a right sidebar (the width is the same as the left sidebar). What do you recommend to do? How to set the settings of the header to ignore the right sidebar space?

Comment: You have to set the children to "width: 100%". And try to find "max-width" - values. You have to delete max-width -values. Because they are preventing your Divs to go on full-width.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to override this css code:

```
.site {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
.site-header {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 4;
}
```

Otherwise if you choose framework then you can easily integrate and understand "matirialize css" OR Bootstrap. 
http://materializecss.com/about.html